wash sale when i average a security and sell at loss

Day 1: Purchase 100 stocks at $10 = $1000
Day 5: Purchase 100 stocks at $5  = $500
Day 10: Sale    200 stocks at $2 =  $400

Overall loss : $1100
Will there be any wash sale loss that is disallowed ?

There is no "wash sale" effect because you completely exited your positions and (apparently) did not re-buy after your sale of 200 lots.
Wash sales rules do not prevent you from taking a loss, they just defer the tax benefit of a loss (to prevent tax loss harvesting) by adjusting the cost basis of your remaining lots after the wash sale. In your case, there are no remaining lots to assign a new cost basis, so the wash sale rule has no effect.
For example, suppose you had only sold 100 stocks on day 10 at $2. The "loss" would then get applied to the cost basis of the remaining 100 stocks. Whether you add the $8 loss from selling the first lot to the second lot or add the $3 loss from selling the second lot to the first lot, the end result is the same. You would have 100 shares with a $13 per share cost basis. When you sold those 100 shares you could then realize the loss. If all of this was in the same tax year the wash sale rules have no real effect. If the ultimate sale was in a subsequent tax year the loss could not be claimed until the year of the final sale. The wash sale rule would prevent you from "harvesting" a loss while continuing to hold 100 shares.
Note that your broker might classify the sale as a "wash sale" on your statement purely because of the timing of the sale, but when you file your taxes you can claim the entire loss.
